# assigning decimal value to double, getting garbage value when multiplying then subtracting

Tags: c++, c, gcc

why do I get garbage value when I do this?

```
int main(){
double shareOutstanding = 3.0000000;
double percentageToSell = 0.3542101;
percentageToSell *= 10;

percentageToSell -= shareOutstanding; //should be 3.542101 - 3.000000

cout << setprecision(16) << percentageToSell << endl;
}
```

It outputs the value I want but with garbage value at the end.
output: .5421010000000002
(The 2 at the end is garbage.)

instead of: .542101
(The value I really want.)

I think the "percentageSell *= 10;" part screws it up. I NEED this line however.

help please.

Comment: This is just how floating point works. If you don't like it then don't use `double`, or output with lower precision.

Comment: It isn't a "garbage" value.  The `double` type works in binary, and there is no exact representation of the decimal `0.3542101` in binary.  This is a much discussed topic on SO and is a basic concept in computer languages / science in general.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. My workaround is to use this trick: round(value*100000)/100000;